# opening python interpreter in command line even when python 3.7 and launcher is not added to path

Tags: python-install

I have installed python without adding python to PATH and disabling py launcher. Yet when i type python -3.7 or py -3.7 in the command prompt, the python interpreter opens. As far as i have researched this should not be possible since python is not added to path and the launcher is also not installed.

So when i opened the installer again to modify the settings, the **"Add Python to environment variables"** checkbox and **"py launcher"** checkbox is enabled. Is this a new feature in python 3.6 and 3.7 installer to automatically add python to path even when **"Add Python 3.6 to Path"** checkbox is not ticked?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please mention which operating system you are using, and where you got the installers from.

Comment: windows 10 and Windows x86 executable installer from the python website

Comment: i have installed python 3.7.0

Comment: Try to run `where.exe python` and see where it is installed. Is it the same as where you've chosen it to install?

Comment: yes. It is the same as where I've installed

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the additional information. Other users that run into the same problem shouldn't have to read the comments to learn whether their problem is actually the same :-)